# JUnit - ComparisonFailure on formatted string

Tags: java, android, junit

My unit tests fails with the following error. Is there any way of comparing more lenient to get the test to pass for such issues?

I do not want to specify the DecimalFormatter more explicitly but make the test more forgiving.

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[-]0.31 mm> but was:<[−]0.31 mm>
```

The test code

```
public void testCode() {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    assertEquals("-0.31 mm", codeUnderTest(-0.000314d);
}
```

Where the code generating the String is

```
private static final int OFFSET_FRACTION_DIGITS_SI = 2;
private static final double UNIT_MULTIPLIER_SI = 1000d; // 1 m in mm
private static final String UNIT_MM = "mm";

public String codeUnderTest(double value) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(OFFSET_FRACTION_DIGITS_SI);
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(OFFSET_FRACTION_DIGITS_SI);

    value *= UNIT_MULTIPLIER_SI;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(df.format(value));

    builder.append(" ");
    builder.append(UNIT_MM);

    return builder.toString();
}
```

**Update:**

More testing revealed that the unicode point returned by the DecimalFormat is Unicode Character 'MINUS SIGN' (U+2212) while the sign specified as expected is Unicode Character 'HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D). So I'm looking for a way of mapping such signs to a single unicode point. The same applies for the thousand-separator that will be Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0) as opposed to the normal Unicode Character 'SPACE' (U+0020).

Comment: Maybe a Locale-related issue ?

Comment: I've tried your code and didn't get the error so make sur that it's not a Locale issue as 2Dee said (i've added  Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); because i had 0,31 as result at first cause of the system default french locale )

Comment: Ah, well. The code is simplified version. In the full version I set the locale as well...

Comment: IMHO the test is simply wrong. You should expect the real outcome, because this is what you always get.

Comment: *shrug* You may be correct @StefanBirkner but the issue sparked my curiosity to whatever there is such a function for unicode-mapping that decreases the point field.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try assertTrue() :

```
public void testCode() {
     assertTrue(codeUnderTest(-0.000314d).equals("-0.31 mm"));
}
```

Comment: That would not change the issue (not being equal). It will change the output: There is no hint anymore as to where the problem lies.